# MessageBrokerServlet failed to initialize due to runtime exception

Tags: java, apache-flex, jboss, blazeds

My application works fine on Windows and Mac, but when I copy the **exactly same JBoss folder** to Debian (or CentOS) I can't figure what happened.

With some research I discovered that something is wrong because if I try to access **/MyApp/messagebroker/amf** I got 404 error, not a blank page.

I have MyApp.ear and inside I have blazeds.war, but apparently, Linux is not performing deploy BlazeDS.

Log:

```
11:31:59,080 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyApp]] (MSC service thread 1-4) MessageBrokerServlet: **** MessageBrokerServlet failed to initialize due to runtime exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    at org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager.newInstance(DTMManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPathContext.<init>(XPathContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
    at flex.messaging.config.XPathServerConfigurationParser.selectSingleNode(XPathServerConfigurationParser.java:52)
    at flex.messaging.config.ServerConfigurationParser.parseTopLevelConfig(ServerConfigurationParser.java:45)
    at flex.messaging.config.AbstractConfigurationParser.parse(AbstractConfigurationParser.java:69)
    at flex.messaging.config.FlexConfigurationManager.getMessagingConfiguration(FlexConfigurationManager.java:77)
    at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

11:31:59,116 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyApp]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Marking servlet MessageBrokerServlet as unavailable
11:31:59,117 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyApp]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Servlet /MyApp threw load() exception: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault cannot be cast to org.apache.xml.dtm.DTMManager
    at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.init(MessageBrokerServlet.java:154) [flex-messaging.jar:2.5.1.173666]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1202) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3655) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3873) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the JDK version - is that same as windows/Mac environment?  This link might help: http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4619030

Comment: You're right, after long period, I changed my server and did a different installation of JDK. Thanks.